# How to insert reversed map with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, api

Is there a way to put map with Google Maps API to a website, but upside down? North must be down, and south up. Is there any possible way to do it? I really need to put map that way and I need really fast solution.

Answer (score 3):

Using the Google Maps API (**Flash Version**) you can rotate the maps

[image]

**Live Example**

http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/SpinningMapDemo/SpinningMapDemo.html

**Source Code**

http://gmaps-samples-flash.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/SpinningMapDemo/srcview/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Not using the Google tiles. You could use CSS transforms to flip the map, but that will muck with mouse interaction and breach terms of service (modifying attribution).

I suggest using OSM tiles, and flipping tile coordinates (number of tiles in the the world at a particular zoom level is 2^zoom).

I wrote a [small library](http://broady.github.com/osm-layer/example.html) to use OSM as a base map, just make the change above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

The below was an expirement in map labs awhile back, but worked within the core google maps and was not exposed via the API.  You maybe able to find out from the G[oogle Maps labs group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-labs) on how they did this?

[image]

Note that the labels are still the right way around.

I have seen other examples where people have rotated and [flipped](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/keir.clarke/web/flip.htm) the map using [CSS3](http://christianheilmann.com/2010/02/09/rotating-maps-with-css3-and-jquery/)

> With the rotation transformations you can arbitarily turn elements. Of
>   course this differs again from browser to browser which is why it made
>   sense to me to find a library plugin that does that. [Zachary Johnson](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html)
>   build one of those and using this together with the Google Maps API it
>   was pretty easy to build a rotating map

[image]

If you flip the map using this method, you could always remove labels using the [v3API styled layers.](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html)